# How do I pretty print generated source in maven project using spoon?

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, inria-spoon

After creating a class using Factory, how can I pretty print the generated class source code ?

Comment: Please could you add some more information. For example: what have you tried so far? What is the result you are getting? What is the result you are expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to create classes with getFactory().Core().createClass(), and write back the generated classes as java source file (.java) in my maven src folder. @JamesWilson

Answer (score 0):

You can call `toString()` on the AST node:

```java
CtClass c = getFactory().Core().createClass();
// fill c with stuff

System.out.println(c.toString())
```